# Как считать последний столбец в таблице MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

у меня есть база данных и там сейчас 2 записи.
я написал в вин формах алгоритм регистрации но дело в том что нужно указать еще и id
и выдает ошибку [image: картинка с ошибкой в visual studio],и как я понял для решения мне нужно просто при каждой регистрации пользователя вводить новое значение id...но как это сделать я незнаю)
кто мне сможет вообще помочь [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В PHPMyAdmin включите [auto_increment](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html) у столбца. Для этого, во вкладке структура, нажмите кнопку "Изменить", правее имени нужного столбца, и поставьте галочку под A_I (скриншот ниже).[image: скриншот]

Comment: спасибо вам,все работает